Lucas numbers remainder inequality problem
Whilst studying Lucas Numbers I came across this statement, where $\varphi$ is the Golden Ratio:

To prove this, one has to show:
\begin{equation}
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq2}\quad:\quad|L_n^{-3}+(-1)^nL_n^{-1}-(-\varphi)^{-n}|<3L_n^{-5}
\end{equation}

I've tried Induction and $L_n = \varphi^n+(-\varphi)^{-n}$ but it didn't get me far.
Thanks in advance for any help.

We can start by proving
$$
\frac1{\phi^n} - \frac1{L_n} = \frac{L_n - \phi^n}{L_n \phi^n} = \frac{(-\phi)^{-n}}{L_n \phi^n} = \frac{(-1)^n}{L_n \phi^{2n}}\tag{1}
$$
and (from multiplying the equation above by $\frac1{\phi^n} + \frac1{L_n}$ on both sides)
$$
\frac1{\phi^{2n}} - \frac1{L_n^2} = \frac{(-1)^n}{L_n \phi^{2n}}\left(\frac1{\phi^n} + \frac1{L_n}\right) = \frac{(-1)^n}{L_n \phi^{3n}} + \frac{(-1)^n}{L_n^2 \phi^{2n}}. \tag{2}
$$
Now we just start using $(1)$ and $(2)$ to rewrite $\frac1{\phi^n}$ and its powers in terms of $L_n$ and its powers:
\begin{align}
\phi^n &= L_n - \frac{(-1)^n}{\phi^n} \\
    &= L_n - (-1)^n \left(\frac1{L_n} + \frac{(-1)^n}{L_n \phi^{2n}}\right) & \text{by (1)} \\
    &= L_n - \frac{(-1)^n}{L_n} - \frac1{L_n \phi^{2n}} \\
    &= L_n - \frac{(-1)^n}{L_n} - \frac1{L_n}\left(\frac1{L_n^2} + \frac{(-1)^n}{L_n \phi^{3n}} + \frac{(-1)^n}{L_n^2 \phi^{2n}}\right) & \text{by (2)} \\
    &= L_n - \frac{(-1)^n}{L_n} - \frac1{L_n^3} - \underbrace{\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{L_n^2 \phi^{3n}} + \frac{(-1)^n}{L_n^3 \phi^{2n}}\right)}_R.
\end{align}
This gives us the form for the expression that we wanted. (By the way, we could keep extending the series just by proving further equations analogous to $(1)$ and $(2)$.) Now we just have to argue that $|R| < \frac{3}{L_n^5}$. This comes down to bounding how good the approximation $\phi^n \approx L_n$ is in a different way.
The relative error $\frac{|L_n - \phi^n|}{\phi^n} = \frac1{\phi^{2n}}$ is decreasing with $n$, and we're only considering $n \ge 2$, so it's bounded by it's value at $n=2$: $\frac1{\phi^4}$, which is less than $0.15$. In other words,
$$
   \frac{|L_n - \phi^n|}{\phi^n} \le 0.15 \implies \frac{L_n}{\phi^n} \le 1.15.
$$
As a result, we can bound $\frac1{L_n^2 \phi^{3n}} = (\frac{L_n}{\phi^n})^3/L_n^5$ by $1.15^3/L_n^5$ and $\frac1{L_n^3 \phi^{2n}} = (\frac{L_n}{\phi^n})^2/L_n^5$ by $1.15^2/L_n^5$. Altogether,
$$|R| \le \frac1{L_n^2 \phi^{3n}} + \frac1{L_n^3 \phi^{2n}} \le \frac{1.15^3 + 1.15^2}{L_n^5} < \frac{2.844}{L_n^5} < \frac{3}{L_n^5}.$$

Thank you for your detailed answer, but could you explain why:
$$
\frac{|L_n - \phi^n|}{\phi^n} \le 0.15 \implies \frac{L_n}{\phi^n} \le 1.15.
$$
Aren't you implying that: $L_n - \phi^n = (-\phi)^{-n} \ge 0$

I'm not assuming that, but I'm using it to get an upper bound. Half the time, $L_n - \phi_n$ is positive, and in that case $\frac{L_n - \phi^n}{\phi^n} \le 0.15$ so $\frac{L_n}{\phi^n} \le 1.15$. The other half of the time, it's negative, but then $\frac{L_n}{\phi^n} \le 1$, so the upper bound of $1.15$ still holds.

Elaborating from comments, here is an alternate solution; it's more powerful, because it allows us to immediately conclude many similar inequalities, but it also requires more background facts.
Begin with the identity
$$
   \phi^n = \frac{L_n + F_n \sqrt5}{2} \tag{1}
$$
and its "conjugate"
$$
   \frac1{(-\phi)^n} = \frac{L_n - F_n \sqrt5}{2} \tag{2}.
$$
Multiplying $(1)$ and $(2)$ together gives us $(-1)^n = \frac{L_n^2 - 5F_n^2}{4}$, which we can use to solve for $F_n$ in terms of $L_n$: $F_n \sqrt 5 = \sqrt{L_n^2 + 4 (-1)^n}$. Substituting this into $(1)$ gives us a relationship between $\phi^n$ and $L_n$ alone:
$$
    \phi^n = \frac{L_n + \sqrt{L_n^2 + 4(-1)^n}}{2}.
$$
This looks a lot like the generating function for the Catalan numbers $C_n = \frac1{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}$, for which we have the identity
$$
   f(x) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 4x}}{2x} = C_0 + C_1 x + C_2 x^2 + C_3 x^3 + C_4 x^4 + \cdots
$$
Specifically, if we substitute $x = -\frac{(-1)^n}{L_n^2}$, we get
$$
    \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 + 4(-1)^n/L_n^2}}{-2(-1)^n/L_n^2} = C_0 - \frac{C_1 (-1)^n}{L_n^2} + \frac{C_2}{L_n^4} - \frac{C_3 (-1)^n}{L_n^6} + \frac{C_4}{L_n^8} - \cdots 
$$
Why did we choose this awkward substitution? Because then the left-hand side simplifies as
$$
   \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 + 4(-1)^n/L_n^2}}{-2(-1)^n/L_n^2} = -(-1)^n L_n \cdot \frac{L_n - \sqrt{L_n^2 + 4(-1)^n}}{2} = -(-1)^n L_n \cdot (L_n - \phi^n)
$$
and if we solve for $\phi^n$, we get the series
\begin{align}
\phi^n &= L_n - \frac{(-1)^n C_0}{L_n} - \frac{C_1}{L_n^3} - \frac{(-1)^nC_2}{L_n^5} - \frac{C_3}{L_n^7} - \frac{(-1)^nC_4}{L_n^9} - \cdots \\
  &= L_n - \frac{(-1)^n}{L_n} - \frac1{L_n^3} - \frac{2(-1)^n}{L_n^5} - \frac{5}{L_n^7} - \frac{14(-1)^n}{L_n^9} - \cdots \tag{3}
\end{align}
One way to truncate $(3)$ at any point we like is to observe that $\frac{C_{k+1}}{C_k} = 4 - \frac{6}{k+2} < 4$ for all $k$, which lets us get an error term as a geometric series.
To get the error term of $\pm 3/L_n^5$, as in the question, we should actually truncate the series $(3)$ after the $2(-1)^n/L_n^5$ term, which leaves an error term of $R'$ satisfying
$$
   |R'| \le \frac{5}{L_n^7} + \frac{5 \cdot 4}{L_n^9} + \frac{5 \cdot 4^2}{L_n^{11}} + \frac{5 \cdot 4^3}{L_n^{13}} + \dots = \frac{5/(L_n^2 - 4)}{L_n^5}.
$$
For all $n \ge 2$, $L_n^2 \ge 9$, so $5/(L_n^2 - 4) \le 1$, and $|R'| \le \frac1{L_n^5}$. We have
$$
    \phi^n = L_n - \frac{(-1)^n}{L_n} - \frac{1}{L_n^3} - \underbrace{\frac{2(-1)^n}{L_n^5} - R'}_R
$$
and $|R| \le \frac{2}{L_n^5} + |R'| \le \frac{3}{L_n^5}$, as desired.
